# All Python scripts broken in ArcMap 10.7.1

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, python-script-tool, toolbox

I recently was attempting to run a Python script that requires the lxml package. I couldn't figure out how to use pip to install it as it always defaults to Python 3.x. So, as a work around I just copied the folders Python made when it installed it for Python 3 and just pasted them into the same folder for Python 2.7 for ArcMap. Well, now all the Python scripts just show a red circle with an X and when I run anything it doesn't run. It just pops up an error message with no text, just a yellow triangle with a ! in it.

Is there a fix or do I need to just reinstall?

Comment: If you can undo the steps you took, you could try it, but whacking the Python dir and letting a Repair fix things might be easier.

Comment: And once you've fixed it... use the full path to call pip - `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\Scripts\pip install lxml`

Comment: If it makes you feel any better similar thing happened to me when I was in grad school.  I tried to update the python 2.7 for arcmap 10.2 or something and it tanked the whole thing.  After an hour on the phone with ESRI they said its best to just reinstall.  The internal python env in ArcMap can be flaky.  My vote is reinstall.